# Flutter only import library in debug mode

Tags: flutter, debugging, build

I am using Android 11 Wireless Debugging to develop my app. Whenever the device automatically locks itself, it takes a while to re-establish the connection for hot reloading.

To overcome this I am using [wakelock](https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock), which I only need to use if my app is in debug mode, not in release mode.

In `lib/main.dart` I have the following code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' as Foundation;
import 'package:wakelock/wakelock.dart';

...

void main() {
  if (Foundation.kDebugMode) {
    Wakelock.enable();
  }
  runApp(App());
}
```

As you can see the `wakelock` package is only used if the app is running in debug mode.

Is there a way to only import `wakelock` if the app is running in debug mode?

Comment: dev dependencies dart can be declared in pubspec.yaml, you can check on this [documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dev-dependencies). I am sorry for my bad.

Comment: @AbdurRohman I have updated my question with more context. Sadly dev dependencies wouldn't work in this case since I am importing the package into `lib/main.dart`

Comment: So you need to use wake lock only to prevent the screen from turning off? If yes, then why not change sleep settings of your device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested it as

`pubspec.yaml`

```
dev_dependencies:
  wakelock: ^0.2.1+1
```

---

Usage

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:wakelock/wakelock.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  if (kDebugMode) {
    print('activating wakelock in debug');
    Wakelock.enable();
  }

  runApp(App());
}
```

---

Sidenote:

If all you need is the device to stop locking itself after some time then try increasing the sleep delay under the `Display` setting on the device itself, or use a setting in developer options called `Stay awake while charging` which allows the device to stay on forever while charging.

Comment: But the documentation says:
"If the dependency is imported from something in your lib or bin directories, it needs to be a regular dependency. If it’s only imported from test, example, etc. it can and should be a dev dependency."

Comment: @ZEHINZ OP wanted a solution where the device would not go to sleep while developing the code. There was no intention of actually keep the screen awake in production mode. Thus, dev_dependency works fine.

Comment: I moved 3 ligraries to dev depedencies, but in release mode app size didn't changed as supposed. Thank you.

Comment: This solution is wrong, because it will still ship the dependency, even in release mode.

Comment: @MartinBraun What makes you believe that? dev_dependencies do not ship in release mode. That's the whole point.

Comment: @andynewman Further research from me has shown `dev_dependencies` package dart code is not shipped in release mode, but their native code is. There was an issue with some native code of a package in release mode that I wanted to use only in debug mode. I was unable to exclude the native code from the build. This behavior is confirmed by someone from the Flutter team as well: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33249#issuecomment-1674277172. The "whole point" doesn't change the fact that the implementation itself is incomplete and thus this solution is a proper full solution.

Comment: @MartinBraun thanks for the pointer. As far as I know, 'dev_dependencies' can further be considered as incomplete as assets declared under its umbrella will also be pulled in the final release. It's another severe limitation of dev_dependencies, IMHO.

Comment: @andynewman Sorry I meant "thus this solution is NOT a proper full solution", but you got what I meant. And yes, I have also found information about assets being shipped into release builds despite being declared under `dev_dependencies`, as you have pointed out.

Comment: @MartinBraun in the end, how do enable development-only features in your code? I mean with dev-only dependencies (including native), and assets? The only (heavyweight) solution I can think of seems to have 2 Flutter projects, with the development project somehow inheriting from the main project and overriding some methods :-(